# Default image not saving in DB

Tags: django

I have a requirement where if a user doesn't upload the image, the default image should be saved in DB for this I am using the default attribute in **FileField** but default image is not saving in DB.

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/',default='NoImage.jpg')
```

Comment: How do you save this model? Can you show the form?

Comment: replace `NoImage.jpg` with a proper path like `default='settings.MEDIA_ROOT/photos/NoImage.jpg'`

Comment: I think if 1000 users doesnt upload any image then instead of inserting same 1000 image in database you can handle like if `file` is null show default image at view only

Comment: You can save default image with the help of django signals

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this. Give the full path prepending `MEDIA_ROOT` like

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/',default='settings.MEDIA_ROOT/photos/NoImage.jpg')
```

But I would suggest keep it `null` because in a case if lots of your user are not uploading any image. You are unnecessarily inserting those number of repetitive default image in database.

In you *django-template* you can handle

```
{% if not file %}

<img src= "{{ MEDIA_URL }}photos/NoImage.jpg"> 

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should leave the field blank if no image is uploaded. It would make easier for auditing and filtering. I would just throw a property:

```
@property
def image_url(self):
  if self.image:
       return self.file.url
  else:
       return "default/image/path/default.jpg"
```